# Does the prepared-statement work this way?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am trying to populate one table in my database with pretty complex data. For this, I am using a generator API (which gives me random data).

```
public void populateCrackers(){
    PreparedStatement psm;
    String queryJoke = "(SELECT jid FROM Jokes WHERE jid=?)";
    String queryHat = "(SELECT hid FROM Hats WHERE hid=?)";
    String queryGift = "(SELECT gid FROM Gifts WHERE gid=?)";

    String query = "INSERT INTO Crackers(cid, name, jid, hid, gid, quantity) VALUES(" +
            "?, " +
            "?, " +
            queryJoke + ", " +
            queryHat + ", " +
            queryGift + ", " +
            "?)";

    System.out.println(query);

    String cracker_String = utils.JSONUtils.getJSON(crackerAPI, client);
    JSONObject crackerJSON = new JSONObject(cracker_String);
    JSONArray crackers = crackerJSON.getJSONArray("results");
    for(int j=0; j<crackers.length(); j++){
        try{
            psm = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            psm.setInt(1,crackers.getJSONObject(j).getInt("cid"));
            psm.setString(2, crackers.getJSONObject(j).getString("cname"));
            psm.setInt(3, crackers.getJSONObject(j).getInt("rjoke"));
            psm.setInt(4, crackers.getJSONObject(j).getInt("rhat"));
            psm.setInt(5, crackers.getJSONObject(j).getInt("rgift"));
            psm.setInt(6, crackers.getJSONObject(j).getInt("cquantity"));

            psm.execute();

            System.out.println(crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("cid") + " "
                    + crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("cname") + " "
                    + crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("cquantity") + " "
                    + crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("rjoke") + " "
                    + crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("rhat") + " "
                    + crackers.getJSONObject(j).get("rgift"));


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method that populates my "Crackers" tab. I am wondering if this be accepted as a prepared statement. When I run it in psql interactive command line tool, exactly that statement with some chosen ids (e.g `INSERT INTO Crackers (cid, name, hid, jid, gid, quantity) VALUES('cid', 'name', (SELECT hid FROM Hats WHERE hid=11), (SELECT jid FROM Jokes where jid=99), (SELECT gid FROM Gifts WHERE gid=13), 5)`  it works flawlessly.

Does my preparedstatement break the Constraint?

Any ideas?

LATER EDIT: The inconsistency is the form of that null values can reach my Crackers table (e.g. Cracker(1, "hello", null, null, 3, 123) appears in the table.

Comment: Why don't you simply run the code, and see if it does what you expect it to do?

Comment: `executeUpdate()` is preferred for DML statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing about Prepared statement. Constraint can be broken by parameters you set to it. And you can run your PLSQL statement as anonimous block in PreparedStatement as well.

Just surround it with BEGIN ... END. only one thing is different - for JDBC parameters are ? mark not :parameter as for PLSQL and there is no way to use named parameter.

That means if you need to use parameter more than once for JDBC you have to have that many ? marks and set all of them.

So, focus on parameters you pass to and their sequence.

Comment: I have tried to use the suggestions above but none worked. I have some sort of inconsistency. If  I insert stuff I sometimes get 2 out of 3 parameters (never 3 out of 3, for example hid never gets loaded) and sometimes 1 out of 3. It's very inconsistent and I think you might be right. I can do this the classic way, but I thought it would be efficient to let everything happen in the db and not make 10000 calls for 300 items.

Comment: INSERT INTO Crackers(cid, name, jid, hid, gid, quantity) VALUES(?, ?, (SELECT jid FROM Jokes WHERE jid = ?), (SELECT hid FROM Hats WHERE hid = ?), (SELECT gid FROM Gifts WHERE gid = ?), ?). This is what my statement looks like after appending.

Comment: Sorry I read from phone and missed that it is Postgres, not Oracle PLSQL. My bad... anyway simple think how you will do the same work if you need to run everything manually from interactive command line tool. I guess you have two choices - pass `null` for not-presented parameters, or you need to construct your statement only with parameters you have. - In both cases your column for each missed parameter must be nullable. And again there is nothing specific about PreparedStatement

Comment: Also things like `(SELECT gid FROM Gifts WHERE gid = ?)` do not make any sense there is no difference with simple `?` for gid (and others).

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, though the prepared statement must be closed, and it would be better to create the statement once, before the for loop.

Now there is `crackers.length()` times a statement created but not closed. That might give problems.

Use the try-with-resouce syntax for automatic closing, irrespective of any exception or return.

```
try (PreparedStatement psm = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    for (int j = 0; j < crackers.length(); j++) {
        ...
        psm.executeUpdate();
```

And call `executeUpdate` instead of the more general `execute`. The resulting update count might be of interest (1/0).

Comment: I did execute update and tried to psm before the query. I still get the same inconsistency.

Comment: Ah, but you did not mention _what_ inconsistency. It could be that the type matching between database and java is a bit more string (long versus int, int versus String). What does the stack trace say? (Add to question)

Answer (score 1):

I realised I had the wrong constraints on my table. I was letting null values in. There was nothing wrong with the prepared statement.

The right query to create the table is this one:

```
String createCrackersQuery = "CREATE TABLE Crackers(" +
            "  cid INTEGER," +
            "  name VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
            "  jid INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "  hid INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "  gid INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "  quantity INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "  CONSTRAINT Cracker_Primary PRIMARY KEY (cid)," +
            "  CONSTRAINT Cracker_Name_Unique UNIQUE(name)," +
            "  CONSTRAINT Joke_Foreign FOREIGN KEY (jid) REFERENCES Jokes(jid)," +
            "  CONSTRAINT Hat_Foreign FOREIGN KEY (hid) REFERENCES Hats(hid), " +
            "  CONSTRAINT Gift_Foreign FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES Gifts(gid)" +
            ")";
```